# matplotlib module not found using jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm just trying to import matplotlib.pyplot using a jupyter notebook. I get the attached error. I have a hunch it has something to do with pip / matplotlib not being in the correct folder / environment but I don't know how to set up my environment so that it can access pip and all of the python modules that are pre-installed!

I moved the entire python folder into the folder I activated jupyter notebook out of, but then nothing else worked.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### I expected no response (successful) but got:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

The notebook is trusted, when I run I get a terminal response that looks like:

Starting buffering for 25c7e3d9-8a1c-486d-848e-0fe7e0298dc7:02a1acc4bbb84ca88e1eb4ec9aa13576

Comment: This usually happens to me when Jupyter is installed in a different environment than matplotlib.  Try to also install Jupyter in that environemnt.

Comment: I'm thinking I have my whole config / environment setup wrong.. I'm fairly new at this. My jupyter project is in a folder in my documents, jupyter-notebook.py is in that folder as well (and where I launch things from). pip, matplotlib etc. are all installed in AppData. Should I alter where things are installed?

Comment: you should use pip to install Jupyter and then it will be available the same way pip is available.  However if you have trouble, suggest using anaconda, which makes these things very easy.  Trying to get all the dependencies installed with pip is often non trivial.